# Determine the Winner of a Game of Australian Football

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, integer, game

In Australian Football, goals are worth 6 points and behinds are worth 1 point. Scores may include the number of goals and behinds, as well as the total score. Given the number of goals and behinds for two different teams, determine which team won the game.

Take four integers `g1, b1, g2, b2` as input, and output two distinct values for whether the first team or the second team inputted won. Input format is flexible, but input order must allow it to be obvious which team is first. For example, `g1, g2, b1, b2` would be allowed, but `b1, g2, g1, b2` would not.

### Test Cases

Test cases will use `true` for the first team winning and `false` for the second team winning. Input is in the format `(g1,b1),(g2,b2)`.

```
(1,0),(0,1)        true
(2,0),(0,11)       true
(10,8),(11,1)      true
(0,0),(1,0)        false
(100,100),(117,0)  false
(7,7),(5,12)       true
(2,0),(0,13)       false
```

As an example, for input `(10,8),(11,1)`, team 1 scored 10 goals and 8 behinds, for a total of \$10*6+8*1=68\$ points, while team 2 scored \$11*6+1*1=67\$ points, so team 1 wins.

No input will be a draw - your program's behavior on draw input does not matter.

Comment: Could we extend for Gaelic football and hurling?

Comment: @TRiG make your own question!

Comment: I'll try to think of something that isn't too close.

Comment: @TRiG, GAA would be identical, just using base-3 instead of base-6.

Comment: Yeah @Shaggy, which is why I couldn't just copy this question to make an equivalent GAA one. Something similar. Maybe including International Rules Football.

Comment: @TRiG, yeah, Compromised Rules might work but to make it a bit more different you could include draws & tie-breakers.

Comment: My TODO list now includes finding out how scoring works in Shinty, Shinty-Hurling, and Super11s Huring, and then producing some sort of super question including all these related games, @Shaggy.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḅ6M
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of integers, `[[g1,b1],[g2,b2]]`, which yields a list `[1]` or `[2]`.
<sub>(Draws would yield `[1,2]`)</sub>

...Or a full program printing `1` or `2`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlYz3////0dHG@kYxOpEG@gYGsfGAgA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlYz3/9HJz3cOeNR05qjew63A6ksIH7UMEdB107hUcPcyP//o6OjDXUUDGJ1FKINdBQMY2O5dKKjjZBEoEKGQLYFSMzQEK7MAKoMbABUFUiLAUTU0BwuDmSZg8RMgbJGmHYYA4ViAQ).

#### How?

```
ḅ6M - Link: list of lists of integers, X
 6  - literal six
ḅ   - convert (X) from base 6 (vectorises)
  M - maximal indices
```

Answer (score 5):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), 12 bytes (WIP language) (OLD)

```
6ɪθɪt6ɪθɪtʈo
```

Outputs `1` for true and `0` for false.

No TIO interpreter yet, but is runnable by cloning the repository above, and calling `python main.py "code here"`.

The TL;DR of the language is that it's a stack-based language where every instruction is a character from the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

Takes in arguments as 4 inputs from STDIN, in the order `g1, b1, g2, b2`. Might be golfed down to less than 12 bytes once loops are fully implemented.

```
6ɪθɪt6ɪθɪtʈo
6            ; Push 6
 ɪ           ; Take number input, push
  θ          ; Pop 2, multiply, push
   ɪ         ; Take number input, push
    t        ; Pop 2, add, push
     6       ; Push 6
      ɪ      ; Take number input, push
       θ     ; Pop 2, multiply, push
        ɪ    ; Take number input, push
         t   ; Pop 2, add, push 
          ʈ  ; Pop 2, if a > b push 1, otherwise 0
           o ; Pop, print
```

Comment: kuːl ˈlæŋgwɪʤ, djuːd!

Comment: aɪ əm nɑːt əˈmjuːzd baɪ ðə hʊd; bɪˈniːθ ɪt ɪz ˈsɪmpli dʒʌst əˈnʌðər stæk-beɪst ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒ. aɪ ˈstrɒŋli dɪsˈkɜːrɪdʒ ju tu ʌpvoʊt ðɪs ˈænsər.

Answer (score 5):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) assembly ([Intellivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellivision)), 9 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> ≈ 12 bytes

A routine taking input in **R0** (\$g_1\$), **R1** (\$b_1\$), **R2** (\$g_2\$) and **R3** (\$b_2\$) and setting the sign flag if the 2nd team wins, or clearing it otherwise.

```
275   PSHR  R5        ; push return address
110   SUBR  R2,   R0  ; R0 -= R2
082   MOVR  R0,   R2  ; R2 = R0
04C   SLL   R0,   2   ; R0 <<= 2
0D0   ADDR  R2,   R0  ; R0 += R2
0D0   ADDR  R2,   R0  ; R0 += R2
0C8   ADDR  R1,   R0  ; R0 += R1
118   SUBR  R3,   R0  ; R0 -= R3
2B7   PULR  R7        ; return
```

The CP-1610 has no multiplication instruction and may only shift by 1 or 2 positions at a time, so we compute the following expression instead:

```
((R0 - R2) << 2) + (R0 - R2) + (R0 - R2) + R1 - R3
```

#### Full test code

```
          ROMW    10              ; use 10-bit ROM width
          ORG     $4800           ; map this program at $4800

          ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
          ;;  test code                                                    ;;
          ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
main      PROC
          SDBD                    ; set up an interrupt service routine
          MVII    #isr,     R0    ; to do some minimal STIC initialization
          MVO     R0,       $100
          SWAP    R0
          MVO     R0,       $101

          EIS                     ; enable interrupts

          SDBD                    ; R4 = pointer to test cases
          MVII    #@@data,  R4
          MVII    #$200,    R5    ; R5 = backtab pointer

@@loop    PSHR    R5              ; save R5 on the stack
          MVI@    R4,       R0    ; load the next test case
          MVI@    R4,       R1    ; into R0 .. R3
          MVI@    R4,       R2
          MVI@    R4,       R3
          CALL    score           ; invoke our routine
          BMI     @@true

          MVII    #$80,     R0    ; set output to '0'
          B       @@output

@@true    MVII    #$88,     R0    ; set output to '1'

@@output  PULR    R5              ; restore R5
          MVO@    R0,       R5    ; draw the output

          SDBD                    ; was it the last test case?
          CMPI    #@@end,   R4
          BLT     @@loop          ; if not, jump to @@loop

          DECR    R7              ; loop forever

@@data    DECLE   1, 0, 0, 1      ; test cases
          DECLE   2, 0, 0, 11
          DECLE   10, 8, 11, 1
          DECLE   0, 0, 1, 0
          DECLE   100, 100, 117, 0
          DECLE   7, 7, 5, 12
          DECLE   2, 0, 0, 13
@@end     ENDP

          ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
          ;;  ISR                                                          ;;
          ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
isr       PROC
          MVO     R0,       $0020 ; enable display

          CLRR    R0
          MVO     R0,       $0030 ; no horizontal delay
          MVO     R0,       $0031 ; no vertical delay
          MVO     R0,       $0032 ; no border extension
          MVII    #$D,      R0
          MVO     R0,       $0028 ; light-blue background
          MVO     R0,       $002C ; light-blue border

          JR      R5              ; return from ISR
          ENDP

          ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
          ;;  routine                                                      ;;
          ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
score     PROC
          PSHR    R5              ; push the return address

          SUBR    R2,       R0    ; R0 -= R2
          MOVR    R0,       R2    ; R2 = R0
          SLL     R0,       2     ; R0 <<= 2
          ADDR    R2,       R0    ; R0 += R2
          ADDR    R2,       R0    ; R0 += R2
          ADDR    R1,       R0    ; R0 += R1
          SUBR    R3,       R0    ; R0 -= R3

          PULR    R7              ; return
          ENDP
```

#### Output

[image: output]

*<sup>screenshot from [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/intv/)</sup>*

---

*<sub>1. A CP-1610 opcode is encoded with a 10-bit value, known as a 'DECLE'. This routine is 9 DECLEs long.</sub>*

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda g,b,G,B:6*g+b>6*G+B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFdJ0nHXcfJykwrXTvJzkzLXdvpf0FRZl6JRpqGoY4BEBpqanLBRIwgIshChgY6FkARFGVgRToGKKqAIiBsaI4ibq5jrmOqY2iEaYexpuZ/AA)

Not incredibly interesting answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 16 bytes

```
#6&
>
 |/
 +
* &
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X9lMjcuOS6FGn0tBm0tLQe3/f0MFAyA0BAA)

Reuses the same `6*a+b` logic for both teams then prints whether the first scores higher than the other

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 22 bytes

```cs
(a,b,c,d)=>a*6+b>c*6+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXooOMk/Lzc@zSbP9rJOok6STrpGja2iVqmWkn2SUDyZT/1lzhRZklqRppGoYGOhY6hoY6hpqa1v8B)

Comment: Also works in JS.

Comment: Or Java by changing the `=>` to `->`

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 34 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$a b c d=a*6+b>c*6+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLJVEhSSFZIcU2UctMO8kuGUim/A8uSQSqsFVQUTBUMABCw///ktNyEtOL/@t6@vx3qcxLzM1MLgYA)

Defines `$ :: Int Int Int Int -> Bool` with arguments taken like `$ g1 b1 g2 b2`

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

```perl6
*×6+*>*×6+*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf6/B0M20tOwj135qrOLFSIU2hJtcqXT8mRVtfIS2/SCEnMy@1@L@GoY6Bpo6GgY6hpgIUlBSVpnJpGMHE4RIQcUMDHQughKEhXAdE3ACsHmQazJy0xJxisAagIQZgSUNzsDRUwlzHHChoqmNopIndZmNNZJMA)

Takes input as 4 integers, and basically just does as the question asks

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
>&(1#.6 1*])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7dQ0DJX1zBQMtWI1/2tyKXClJmfkKxgCVaQBsSGEawTjQvmGBgoWQAFDQ5gCA7ACoC6YvAEYg5SYwwTNgTBNwVTB0EgBzVTj/wA)

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch 3.0 <s>17</s> 16 blocks, <s>160</s> 143 bytes

*Score comes from proposed scoring method [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5013/78850)*

*1 block/17 bytes saved thanks to @A* (or Uzer_A on scratch)_

[image: Program in better blocks]

[Try it on Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/332406370/)

*As Scratchblocks*:

```
when gf clicked
repeat(2
ask[]and wait
set[m v]to((answer)*(6)
ask[]and wait
change[m v]by(answer
add(m)to[x v
end
say<(item(1) of [x v]) > (m)
```

### Answer History

[image: Program in blocks]

Pretty much a port of my Keg answer.

[Try it on Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/332039766/)

Input is in the form of `g1, b1, g2, b2`

*In Scratchblocks syntax*

```
when gf clicked
repeat(0
set[m v]to(0
ask[]and wait
change[m v]by((answer)*(6)
ask[]and wait
change[m v]by(answer
add(m)to[x v
end
say<(item(1) of [x v]) > (m)
```

Now I know what you're saying... *why golf in scratch?!?*
Well, it's fun. That's why. Also, Scratch is unique in that it isn't very often featured here on CGCC.

Comment: [51 bytes?](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=define%20%28a%29%28b%29%28c%29%28d%0Asay%3C%28%28%28a%29%2A%286%29%29%2B%28b%29%29%3E%28%28d%29%2B%28%28c%29%2A%286)

Answer (score 3):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 22 bytes

```
6OxcOasz6OxcOaclmzh1co
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/9/MvyLZP7G4CkIn5@RWZRgm5///b6RgwGWgYGgMAA)

Takes the input as 4 delimited integers, and returns 0 for the first team winning, 1 for the second.

### Explanation:

```
6Oxc                   | Multiplies the first number by 6
    Oa                 | Adds the second number
        6Oxc           | Multiplies the third number by 6
            Oa         | Adds the fourth number
      sz      clmz     | Subtract this from the first team's score
                  h1co | Print 0 if the first team's score is greater, 1 otherwise
```

-4 bytes if nondistinct results are allowed:

```
6OxcOasz6OxcOaclmo
```

Will output the score difference; positive results mean the first team win, negative means the second team win.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 11 bytes

```scala
_*6+_>_*6+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnUM2VkpqmkAtkaiQWpRdbKTgWFSVWRgeXFGXmpcdqWoXmZZYo2AKVlSXmKBQn5xelWml45pXoIGFNWzun/Pyc1MQ82//xWmba8XZg8j9XAdCMkpw8DbA2DUMdAyA01NREEzeCiGNKGBroWADFsWgBa9AxwKIDKA7ChuZYZM11zHVMdQyNcLnAGChRy1X7HwA)

Takes 4 Integers in the order of `g1 b1 g2 b2`.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>45</s> <s>38</s> <s>36</s> <s>32</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
,[>,[<++++++>-],]-[[-<]>>]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOJ9pGGwzsdGN1YnWjo3VtYu3sYu30/v83NzAwBAA)

Thanks to @Jo King for -8 bytes

Input is b1, g1, b2, g2 (goals and behinds are exchanged)
Prints þ, if team 1 won. Prints null, if team 2 won.

code:

```
[tape: p1, p2, print marker]

[Get input and calculate scores]
,               input behinds of team 1
[               while input
  >,                go to next cell and input goals of team
  [<++++++>-]       add it 6 times to behinds
,]              repeat this with the second pair of values

[Determine, which one is better]
-               set print marker
[               while score of both teams is greater than zero
  [-<]              decrement and go to previous cell (team 1 or empty cell/in the first run, it will decrement the print marker a second time)
  >>                return to team 2 (or two cells to the right of the first team that became 0)
]
>               go one cell right. If team 1 won, we are at the print marker now
                If team 2 won, we are one cell right of the print marker
.           Print that
```

Comment: I dont think this works with inputs greater than 10, but a great solution anyway. (Would note it down still). Might give a try to outgolf that later :)

Comment: Yes, inputs greater than 9 are at least a bit tricky, because the code only uses one character per input. You need to use the next ASCII characters (`:;<=>?` etc.) if you want to enter higher scores.

Comment: Is "input as character code except null" an option? Plus, both scores must be equal, when being integer-divided by 256, at least when you use tio.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 10 bytes (SBCS)

```
(2|¿¿6*+)>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fw6jm0P5D@820tDXt/v83NDDgAmEgaWgOAA)

As an Australian, I approve of this question.

Input taken as:

```
b1
g1
b2
g2
```

And 0 means team 2 and 1 means team 1

### Explained

```
(2| #twice
¿¿  #get input in the form of bn, gn where n is the team number
*6+ #multiply the goals by 6 and add the values
)>  #compare the two values to determine the winner
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>39</s> <s>35</s> <s>31</s> 26 bytes

```c
e(a,b,c,d){a=(a-c)*6>d-b;}
```

0 is false

1 is true

Input to function is (g1, b1, g2, b2)

Thanks to Doorknob for -5 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5BCsIwEEXX5hShIiQysUlFI1R7EjfppGpAo2hdlZ49xrjUyGcGPm8eDIojYpg6j@en7ej20Vt3XZya0DEDLSBYPpgdMwL5fN1Y0dZjcL6nF@M843Qgk9s99gMrZnbvC@iYAhmjOK@/WfVhv6GSsIksoyYRZMaM7D1KZy40aFiBqv59tUywLKlKkTFxEzKGFw)

Comment: You can remove the space after `return`, but you can also abuse an implementation detail for [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY5BCsIwEEXX5hShIiQysUlFI1R7EjfppGpAo2hdlZ49xrjUyGcGPm8eDIojYpg6j@en7ej20Vt3XZya0DEDLSBYPpgdMwL5fN1Y0dZjcL6nF@M843Qgk9s99gMrZnbvC@iYAhmjOK@/WfVhv6GSsIksoyYRZMaM7D1KZy40aFiBqv59tUywLKlKkTFxEzKGFw "C (gcc) – Try It Online").

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh, 19 bytes

[try it online!!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J9fpaFZ/V9Dw0xLxVBbxcgOSBtrq5hoav5PTc7IV1Cx56rlyq9SMFQwAEJDENMIwgSzDQ0ULIBMiARYWMEAIm4AwYbmEAFzIDRVMDRCMsD4PwA)

```zsh
((6*$1+$2>6*$3+$4))
```

Input order is `g1 b1 g2 b2`. Exit codes `0==true` and `1==false`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
6δβZk
```

Input as a nested list `[[g1,b1],[g2,b2]]`. Output `0` if team 1 wins and `1` if team 2 wins.

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy* for reminding me about `δ`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f7NyWc5uisv//j4421DGI1Yk20DGMjQUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/s3Nbzm2Kyv6v8z86OtpQxyBWJ9pAxzA2VkchOtoIxoXyDQ10LIAChoYwBQZgBSBdUHmgWgOwkKE5TNBcxxwoYKpjaIRmqHFsbCwA).

**Explanation:**

Apparently arbitrary base conversion on nested lists doesn't work without an explicit <s>map</s> outer product.

```python
 δβ    # Apply arbitrary base-conversion double-vectorized,
6      # using the (implicit) input-list of lists and 6 as base
       # (i.e. [a,b] becomes 6a+b (or to be more precise: 6¹a + 6⁰b))
   Z   # Get the maximum of this mapped list (without popping the list itself)
    k  # And get the 0-based index of this maximum in the mapped list
       # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 62 bytes

```
([((({})({}){}){}{}[(({})({}){}){}{}]<(())>)(<>)]){({}())<>}{}
```

Outputs `1` if the first team lost, and `0` if they won (or tied).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyNaQ0OjulYThMGoujYaXSDWRkNDU9NOU8PGTjNWsxooA@Ta2AFl/v83UjAAQkNjAA)

```
# Input: G B g b

   (                                 <(())>)                   # Push 1 under...
    ({})({}){}){}{}                                            #   6G + B
                   [                ]                          #   Minus
                    (({})({}){}){}{}                           #   6g + b
                                             <>                # Switch stacks
([(                                         (  )])             # Push 0 under -(6G+B-6g+b)
                                                   ({}())<>    # Add 1 and switch stacks...
                                                  {        }   #   until one stack reaches 0
                                                            {} # Pop, leaving either 1 or 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 35 bytes

```powershell
param($g,$b,$h,$c)$g*6+$b-gt$h*6+$c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVdRyVJRyVDRyVZUyVdy0xbJUk3vUQlA8RK/v//vzkQmv43NAIA)

Comment: [Alternative 35 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYkxCoAwEAR7X3HFYqER7gSNjY9R0aQQFCNYiG@PMZFlYYbZt2s@nJ3X1WPpbw@jMCpYhanHcBiXwRRtibEyJ@xHk3@yHAvpsIakjiLEYRK5TpxEmLrAf4qB@C@cLprYvw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 751 bytes

```
the game:a game o soccer
for a moment of my fun,i kicked my leg
o,i hurt a player
o.m.gee,o no
suddenly i then apologized a little
o.m.gee,o no
but really,i loved a good soccer battle
a game i am doing,i love it
there is a game,a twenty-to-one unwinnable match(as we called it,i mean)a match we won
a wonder of an event i saw
i played,i go in again
i am happy in a match-up of teams,i am pumped
then o,a coach i saw played soccer
i know i do admire a game o soccer
o,a match was not a bummer,and also i am making in an extra score
i think i saw a split net,a hole i ripped out a net
i am ready to win a match
o,my people and i love a sport,a bit o soccer
i am going in a game,i score,i win
o really,i am doing a game o soccer
play ball
i am gonna wi-n
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?ZVLbjpwwDH3PV/ixlZhVL2/9G0M8IZrEjkJYlv789gQYjdoKiUBiH59L2iwUOMsvPhYyWmyapLq7VWLKlkUb2Z3yTvdVh0iPOD3E9/8kwRl25rU21JbEOxrtLb8FkcFIzS2r96Jpp0htFiUulizE3wBgSrG1JH83jGujKpzSDuBk70dhMPMXLxr5aLroRuJM3qKGq5xic5hU8bHQWTQwtQ0q9luzm6nQqltU5TEJZW7T/IUX2oQmTMW42ACVhfUrn8f9bDPFSLw9KMANVpL37kykhTcXT/EencEoQmfgqO5gN3Mp@7F3wt3W0hGacF6Go6KsuYh3h0EGtpMxph7IF@4zFLivtuHIG7HPETL/za0DXLQhS60nM645Sx1YYWZa7HQt8wO2HcQg5qNVpmWyKq5HFfVxEcBuQVCk0oA8W@qm11jAmGzt6Dg5lSI3v1Mz2l5qwQc3pYgVNHYCV0wd1mqHHAFuL4HACfYkduYXT2JYAezsdT@e2f9nQncNNyWlJyDiRvNNP3@4b3i@//wc2f8B)

Boy, this was a tough one to write.

Input is in the following format:

```
g1
b1
g2
b2
```

This gives the error code of "Mismatched IF/EIF" if the first team wins, and "Unexpected EOF" if the second team wins. (Incidentally, a tie is treated as the second team winning).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 34 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(1*),
$1$1$1$1$1$1
(1*);\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0vDUEtTh0vFEAHBQtYxhir//xvqGFgb6BhyGUFoQy5DAx0La0NDoJABUAgoDRQBShgA2YbmQJ65jrm1qY6hEUyHMQA) Link includes test cases. Outputs `1` if the second team doesn't win and `0` if it does. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
(1*),
$1$1$1$1$1$1
```

In each pair, multiply the first number by six and add the second.

```
(1*);\1$
```

Check whether the second number is greater than the first. Alternatively, you could use `^(1*);\1` which would output `0` if the first team wins and `1` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

## [ABC-assembler](https://github.com/Ourous/abc-wrapper-linux), <s>111</s> 74 bytes

```
.o 0 4 iiii
f
	subI
	pushI 6
	mulI
	addI
	subI
	pushI 0
	ltI
.d 0 1 b
	rtn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBbbsQgDEW/YRXewERkNOoC@pdVWLwyoXII4jFSpdk7JaSTafkxl2sf20ilLzIluyqysQ4py5gBsUf@ikwVRwYQBMScMNlcAh8MjCA4@1oDoInuYSMffEtBPmzdeueyUNKCfjMWUH9rsug8puC8bWkNJDooRdCSCOfi9c4QjaI4mx3RJ6ojKWyhXceze8yeP2GxFGyEvTC7zUPeOgnyYkHqXCSd3gEW/N2pDzc13BPu40uJXV3/eur0PnZ1Pea@gWvn@IW5dvbv08xZKmo6izhbCzUpjZn@W20NytPB6xu3pWqtF/UD)

It doesn't use anything above the most basic stack operations:

```
subI    | B = [g1-g2,b1,b2]
pushI 6 | B = [6,g1-g2,b1,b2]
mulI    | B = [6*g1-6*g2,b1,b2]
addI    | B = [6*g1+b1-6*g2,b2]
subI    | B = [6*g1+b1-6*g2-b2]
pushI 0 | B = [0,6*g1+b1-6*g2-b2]
ltI     | B = [0<6*g1+b1-6*g2-b2]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 32 bytes

```php
fn($g,$b,$G,$B)=>$g+$b/6>$G+$B/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/BCoMwDAbge58iSA6KQa1jOnA68OJDOA8qVgdDi7rT2LO7TmVOWEqh8OVvG9nI6XyRjWQMRTiJVseasCBMCGMjjLA2sbC9CBMTY9ubAtU3VsM4QAgpA1UpJ0ctnhGsZdsw9o9qUXfRjXfKHTop3NI7nZPk7G4W@X34hhV/NveXpj375NORuPv/5fVfh19dwpmaUXR9lZcN6Ouw@QDzyYDnHK/KpgP91o4GCt2yrBUt0K6tFrDX9AY)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 18 bytes

```perl
say<>*6+<>><>*6+<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sdLGTstM28bODkr//2/CZcxlxGX4L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhAQA)

Input is line separated:

```perl
g1
b1
g2
b2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
6#+#2>6#3+#4&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b730xZW9nIzkzZWFvZRO1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoODcqyavkM1V7WhjgEQGtbqcFUbQZhgtqGBjgWQCZEAC@sYQMSBTBA2NIcImOuY65jqGBohGWBcy1X7HwA)

straightforward and boring

Answer (score 1):

## Whitespace, 115 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _STDIN_as_integer][T    T   T   _Retrieve_integer][S S S T  T   S N
_Push_6][T  S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   T   _STDIN_as_integer][T    T   T   _Retrieve_integer][T    S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   T   _STDIN_as_integer][T    T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    T   S N
_Push_6][T  S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   T   _STDIN_as_integer][T    T   T   _Retrieve_input][T  S S S _Add][T   S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   N
_If_negative_jump_to_Label_NEGATIVE][S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
N
N
_Exit_Program][N
S S N
_Label_NEGATIVE][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Prints `0` if team 1 wins and `1` (could also be `-1` for the same byte-count) if team 2 wins.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIAxJcnBBBhDhIAkUAn0IgBvG4QFo4QTJAANYNEgby//83NDDgAmNDcy4DAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer g1 = STDIN as integer
Integer t1 = g1*6
Integer b1 = STDIN as integer
t1 = t1 + b1
Integer g2 = STDIN as integer
Integer t2 = g2*6
Integer b2 = STDIN as integer
t2 = t2 + b2
If(t1 - t2 < 0):
  Goto NEGATIVE
Print 0
Exit program

Label NEGATIVE:
  Print 1
  (implicitly exit with an error)
```

One minor note: since the inputs are guaranteed to be \$\geq0\$, I'm using that to my advantage to re-use the inputs as heap-addresses for the subsequent inputs. With challenges which can have negative inputs I'd have to re-push `0` as heap-address, since heap-addresses cannot be negative.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as a 2D-array. Outputs `1` for team 1, `0` for a draw or `-1` for team 2.

```
mì6 rg
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bew2IHJn&input=WwpbMSwwXQpbMCwxXQpd)

```
mì6 rg     :Implicit input of array
m          :Map
 ì6        :  Convert from base-6 digit array
    r      :Reduce by
     g     :  Sign of difference
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,x,y{b-y>6*x-=a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ0mnQqeyOkm30s5Mq0LXNrH2f4FCWrShjgEQGsZygThGEA6UZ2igYwHkwCTBUjoGMDkgB4QNzWFC5jrmOqY6hkYoRhnH/gcA)

Worked around the boring solution, saved a byte and called it a day.

Answer (score 1):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 84 bytes

Just the simple "multiply by 6, sum and compare" aproach, except the math support is extremelly lacking.

```
{@set*A argv.0,6}{@incbyargv.1 A}{@set*B argv.2,6}{@incbyargv.3 B}0{@ifB is lowerA}1
```

Outputs `0` for false and `01` for true.

---

Ungolfed:

```
{@// multiply the first argument by 6}
{@set* teamA argv.0, 6}

{@// add the 2nd argument to the previous result}
{@inc by argv.1 teamA}

{@// same as before, for argument 3 and 4}
{@set* teamB argv.2, 6}
{@inc by argv.3 teamB}

{@echo 0}
{@// alternative: teamA is greater than teamB}
{@if teamB is lower than teamA}
    {@echo 1}
{@/}
```

Everything should be clear with the comments (`{@// ... }`) added.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 44 bytes

```go
func f(a,b,x,y int)bool{return a*6+b>=x*6+y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZx8WVmVuQX1SioJSWW6L0P600L1khTSNRJ0mnQqdSITOvRDMpPz@nuii1pLQoTyFRy0w7yc62AkhV1kIUgwzR0FSo5lJQUAAaoRdQBNSUk6eRpmGoo2AARoaamlhkDUAyYMLQHKgMqKb2PwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <del>7</del> 6 bytes

I am quite impressed that MathGolf has *8* block-starting builtins!

```
2É6*+>
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/ocKeZlrbd//@GBgYKYGxormAAAA)

### Explanation

```
2      Constant 2
 É     Start code block of length 3
  6*   Take one input * 6 (with implicit input)
    +  Take another input and add them
     > Take Greater than of the two constants in the stack
There is an implicit output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 101 bytes

```
(Lots of whitespace)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYvBCYBQDEPPyRQZwd5cR@SD3gQFx6@Jni2lTfLae9uvcR7LOropUBIgQmKst35ivG1Ke7NEzLSPiuZ3kI@UCbtr4swq1gM)

readable version:

```
lstl        call readint
sssttsl     push 6
tssl        mult
lstl        call readint
tsss        add
lstl        call readint
sssttsl     push 6
tssl        mult
lstl        call readint
tsss        add
tsst        sub
sssl        push 0
slt         swap
lttsl       jn otherteam
ssstl       push 1
lsssl       otherteam:
tlst        printi
lll         end

lssl        readint:
sssl        push 0
sls         dup
tltt        readi
ttt         retrieve
ltl         ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(a,b,c,d)a*6+b>c*6+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRJ0knWSdFM1HLTDvJLhlIpvxP0zDUMQBCQ02uNA0jCBPMNjTQsQAyIRJgYR0DiDiQCcKG5hABcx1zHVMdQyMkA4w1/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
qhQeo+*6hNeN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzAjMDVfW8sswy/V7/9/DSMdA00dDQMdQ2NNAA)

Pretty simple but Im happy with it. Takes `(g1,b1),(g2,b2)`, returns `True` or `False`

### How it works

```
qhQeo+*6hNeN
qhQ          - The first input is equal to..
   eo        - The last input of a sorted list (implicitly the input)
     +*6hNeN - With the key 6 * first (hN) + last (eN)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

Puts the code block into a function.

```
{6*+@@6*+>}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v9pMS9vBAUjY1f63SivNS7bmMjQwUABjQ3MFAwWQ2H8A)